# Implementing RecyclerView with Sectioned Header based on Category

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement RecyclerView with custom sectioned header based on list's category. I already have a list that's sorted based on their category, so I want to inflate header if and only if one row's category is different from preceding row's category. I've been figuring out how to do it but something bothering me here. It worked, but does not display the right row. I think it's because of the item count which is increased due to the header. Can anyone help me?

Here is my adapter :

```
List<Notes> notes;
OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;
private static final int TYPE_CATEGOORY = 0;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
String changing = "";

public OneNoteAdapter(List<Notes> logs) {
    this.notes = logs;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if(viewType == TYPE_CATEGOORY){
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(parent.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.category_header, parent, false);
        return new HeaderViewHolder(itemView);
    }else{
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(parent.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.learn_card, parent, false);
        return new ItemViewHolder(itemView);
    }

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(holder instanceof HeaderViewHolder){
        Notes note = notes.get(position);
        ((HeaderViewHolder) holder).vCategoryText.setText(note.category);
    }else {
        ItemViewHolder item = (ItemViewHolder) holder;
        Notes note = notes.get(position);
        item.vNotesNote.setText(note.notes);
        item.vNotesCat.setText(note.category);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if((!(notes.get(position).category).equals(changing))){
        changing = notes.get(position).category;
        return TYPE_CATEGOORY;
    }else{
        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return notes.size();
}



public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    protected TextView vNotesNote, vNotesCat;

    private final Context context;

    public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        vNotesNote = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.notes_notes);
        vNotesCat = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.notes_category);
        context = itemView.getContext();
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(mItemClickListener != null){
            mItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getPosition());
        }
    }
}

public class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected TextView vCategoryText;

    public HeaderViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        vCategoryText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_header_text);
    }
}

public interface OnItemClickListener{
    public void onItemClick(View v, int poition);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener (final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener){
    this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
}
```

}

Thank You

Comment: Can you share your entire class with view holder etc. and also the listener where you set header category. Looks like your header always shows your first item's category in the list right now.

Comment: yes, actually that was what im intended. fyi, my list is already ordered by category. So the header's text should be its following item's category. Okay, i just edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace your `onBindViewHolder` and `getItemViewType` methods with following:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof HeaderViewHolder) {
        ((HeaderViewHolder) holder).vCategoryText.setText(notes.get(position + 1).category);
    } else {
        ItemViewHolder item = (ItemViewHolder) holder;
        Notes note = notes.get(position);
        item.vNotesNote.setText(note.notes);
        item.vNotesCat.setText(note.category);

        if (position + 1 < notes.size() &&
            !notes.get(position + 1).category.equals(note.category)) {
            notes.add(position + 1, null);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (notes.get(position) == null) {
        return TYPE_CATEGOORY;
    } else {
        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }
}
```

And you can delete `String changing = "";`.